# when i run my code I get the following result []object object] [object object] but should be giving me an ordered array

Tags: javascript

```
 var rangeArray= new Array();
       rangeArray.push(parseRangeString(1, "< -4 & < 10"));
       rangeArray.push(parseRangeString(2, "< 15 & < 19"));
       rangeArray.push(parseRangeString(3, "<= 50 & <= 123"));
       rangeArray.push(parseRangeString(4, "< -99 & < -23"));
       rangeArray.push(parseRangeString(5, "< 7 & < 55"));
       alert(rangeArray)
       var orderedArray = orderRanges(rangeArray);
       alert (orderedArray)
```

it has something to do with the code above but cant see it, could u help me

Comment: parseRangeString is a function that i have created incase you are wondering

Comment: And what do the functions return? `[object Object]` is the default string representation of objects, so everything is probably fine. Just don't use `alert` to debug your code, use `console.log`.

Comment: Can you set up a JSFiddle? It's impossible to answer if we can't see what `orderRanges()` does.

Comment: it is because my array contains Range objects which I have created and javascript does not know how to display them.  When the array contained strings which are built in javascript obects it knew how to display them! so how do i rectify this

Answer (score 0):

`parseRangeString(1, "< -4 & < 10")` returns some object (or hash like `{}`), it's view as a string is `[Object object]`. When you alert your array the programm convert it to string, dysplays you it is array, and then dysplays all elements of array in it's string view.